# Naive approaches to detecting plagiarism?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say you wanted to compare essays by students and see if one of those essays was plagiarized. How would you go about this in a naive manner (i.e. not too complicated approach)? Of course, there are simple ways like comparing the words used in the essays, and complicated ways like using compressing functions, but what are some other ways to check plagiarism without too much complexity/theory?

Comment: This is one of those things where doing something badly is probably much worse than not doing it at all. When I was in college, I was once given an F on a paper and accused of plagiarism on the basis of one of these naive plagiarism detectors -- the article I was accused of plagiarizing was *citing my paper*, with attribution! The plagiarism detector only included the matching sections and cut the context (including the citation) out of the other paper! Just don't do it.

Comment: It should still be helpful as long as you don't let the detector make any final decisions - just finding similar documents for the user to look at.

Comment: I agree. This is more of a theoretical look at things rather than a practical application. I dont plan to build a plagiarism detector based on this haha

Comment: Are you only comparing the essays submitted by the students or including other documents(sources)?

Answer (score 2):

There are several papers giving several approaches, I recommend reading [this](http://www.labri.fr/perso/fleury/courses/PdP/Plagiat/Fast_Plagiarism_Detection_System.pdf)
The paper shows an algorithm based on an index structure
built over the entire ﬁle collection.

So they say their algorithm can be used to ﬁnd similar code fragments in a large software system.  Before the index is built, all the ﬁles in the
collection are tokenized. This is a simple parsing problem, and can be solved in
linear time. For each of the N ﬁles in the collection, The output of the tokenizer
for a ﬁle F_i is a string of n_i tokens.

[image]

[here](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/prechelt/Biblio/jplagTR.pdf) is other paper you could read

Other good algorithm [is a scam based algorithm](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/IMECS2011/IMECS2011_pp272-277.pdf) that consists on detecting plagiarism by making comparison on a set of words that are common between test document
and registered document. Our plagiarism detection system, like many Information Retrieval systems, is evaluated with metrics of precision and recall.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Dick Grune's [similarity comparator](http://dickgrune.com/Programs/similarity_tester/), which claims to work on natural language texts as well (I've only tried it on software). The algorithms are described as well. (By the way, his book on parsing is really good, in my opinion.)